# Perl - awk syntax error @array

Tags: perl, syntax, awk

I need some assistance with getting awk to work in perl, or find a better alternative...

This code, returns an error about syntax at |  when using the awk command to parse the detail.

```
my @LIST = `/bin/sh $DIR/ami-show.sh Version: | awk '{print $3}'`;
```

The exact error is

```
Use of uninitialized value $3 in concatenation (.) or string at test line 20, <STDIN> line 1.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT: RESOLVED!!

Added \ to the '{print \$3}' all works as expected for this command.

Comment: awk from within perl is just plain stupid, since perl can do everything that awk can and more and you will waste a process.

Comment: Thank for the heads up lol... "stupid" is kind of a harsh way to put it though right!? Im new to perl and using methods that may not be "best practice", which is why i asked for possible better alternatives!!  Anyway, i figured out the problem... adding \$3 instead of $3 in the print was the trick

Comment: @NickHatfield I don't use perl so I can't tell you what the right approach is, but that just can't be it. It's like struggling to start a campfire in your microwave and figuring out you need to leave the door open so it doesn't run out of air. Yeah that'll "solve your problem", but....

Comment: Well at least you should be congratulated for using `strict` and `warnings`.

Comment: Wasn't my intention to sound harsh :-) See e.g. #6 on how to use perl in `awk-mode` https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/the_top_10_tricks_of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have established already, the problem lies with the interpolation of the variable `$3`. Instead of escaping the `$` to fix the problem, this can be circumvented completely by using perl to split the output of your command.

You should be able to do something like this in perl, using [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) rather than relying on `awk`. Note that the `$3` used in your `awk` command corresponds to index number 2, due to arrays starting from index 0.

```
my $output = `/bin/sh $DIR/ami-show.sh Version:`;
my $column = (split ' ', $output)[2];
```

`split` takes a regular expression as its first argument (the pattern) and splits the string contained in the second argument. The code above splits the output of the command on any amount of white space, which is the same as what `awk` does by default.

**edit**: If you saw my first edit, I simply did `split $output`, omitting the pattern argument. This is actually valid, as not specifying a pattern invokes the same, awk-like behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You want to prevent Perl from interpolating the `$3` variable.  You could try to separate your `awk` command into its own string for better interpolation control:

```
my $awk = q(awk '{print $3}');
my @LIST = `/bin/sh $DIR/ami-show.sh Version: | $awk`;
```

Comment: nice...this is one for the books, I may try this if I run into another awk situation... or simply learn to use perl for the function lol